# Error converting value to type while posting data in Asp.net Core API through Postman

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-2.2

I am developing an API in Asp.net Core. I have Contact and Jobtitle Models.

**Contact.cs**

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    //public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public MaritalStatus MaritalStatus { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public JobTitle JobTitle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Mobile { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender
{
    Male = 0,
    Female = 1
}

public enum MaritalStatus
{
    Unmarried = 0,
    Married = 1,
    Divorced = 2,
    Widowed = 3
}
```

**Jobtitle.cs**

```
public class JobTitle
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string NameAr { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Postman to post my JSON data to Insert a new value in contact but its giving me error:

**JSON Value**

```
{
"firstName": "XYZ",
"middleName": "",
"lastName": "ABS",
"fullName": "XYZ ABS",
"gender": 0,
"dateOfBirth": "1987-03-05T07:49:33",
"maritalStatus": 1,
"jobTitle": "1",
"email": "demo@demo.com",
"phone": 12345678,
"mobile": 12345678,
"address": "84445 abc Hill",
"photo": "",
"isDeleted": false,
"createdOn": "2018-03-07T03:41:44",
"updatedOn": "2018-03-07T03:41:44"
}
```

It is giving me an error for converting the value to type Jobtitle object.

```
"errors": {
"jobTitle": [
  "Error converting value \"1\" to type 'TransConnectApi.Models.JobTitle'. Path 'jobTitle', line 9, position 17."
]
}
```

I understand that the problem is the API needs object of jobtitle in reference but I don't know how to give that since it does not hit my post breakpoint in Visual Studio. So how can I take the value of jobtitle and convert it?

Comment: jobTitle is accepting an `object` of type JobTitle and you are passing `integer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an object with only `Id` key in it like:

```
{
  "firstName": "XYZ",
  "middleName": "",
  "lastName": "ABS",
  "fullName": "XYZ ABS",
  "gender": 0,
  "dateOfBirth": "1987-03-05T07:49:33",
  "maritalStatus": 1,
  "jobTitle": {  // here just pass object with Id key
    "Id": "1"
  },
  "email": "demo@demo.com",
  "phone": 12345678,
  "mobile": 12345678,
  "address": "84445 abc Hill",
  "photo": "",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "createdOn": "2018-03-07T03:41:44",
  "updatedOn": "2018-03-07T03:41:44"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

-edit: You said in the comment and I updated the answer. If you don't want to send JobTitle with JSON, just remove that line. It will map NULL as your JobTitle object. So you can handle it in the backend code.

```
{
"firstName": "XYZ",
"middleName": "",
"lastName": "ABS",
"fullName": "XYZ ABS",
"gender": 0,
"dateOfBirth": "1987-03-05T07:49:33",
"maritalStatus": 1,
"email": "demo@demo.com",
"phone": 12345678,
"mobile": 12345678,
"address": "84445 abc Hill",
"photo": "",
"isDeleted": false,
"createdOn": "2018-03-07T03:41:44",
"updatedOn": "2018-03-07T03:41:44"
}
```

Comment: Actually Jobtitle is already there in db I don't want to add new. I am just pointing Id of Jobtitle while creating new Contact.

Comment: Then don't send it. it will be null by this way :)

Comment: @ShabbirIsmail Check posted answer